# index.php is not opening and running as download the file

Tags: php, apache

When I attempt to navigate to the PHP script at http://localhost/project/admin, I expect to see the script results in my web browser.

Instead, I see a dialog box for downloading the file with the message below:

> You have chosen to open `<filename>`, which is a: `application/x-httpd-php` from: http://localhost 
>   What should Firefox do with this file? `Open with...` • `Save...` • etc.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Did you get your answer? Which was it?

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not correctly installed on the server or Apache is not using mod_php

In the case of this happening in IIS. I would say that the mimetype is not setup correctly and that the server doesn't know how to handle the extension ".php"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an incorrect `Content-type` header is being sent.  This header sets the mime-type for the data the browser receives and, if the browser doesn't have a handler to render that specific mime-type, it will ask to open/save the file instead.

I would start by checking your PHP file for a `header()` statement and a mis-typed content-type.

Comment: Looks like apache is tresting this PHP file as application/x-httpd-php and not text/html (/xhtml, html+xml etc.).

Comment: if the php file isn't being executed, there is no modification to the php file that will cause it to be executed. This is an apache-level issue.