# Apache downloads php files instead of executing script

Tags: php, apache

I just set up a local web server on a new Mac running 10.6 (Apache2 / PHP / Mysql). Everything seems to be working fine except when I navigate to *SOME* (not most) pages Apache downloads php files instead of executing them.

I thought this might have something to do with the time it takes php to execute the script so I increased my "max_execution_time" but it didn't help.

I wish I could give more details but the error logs don't output anything so I really have no idea why this is happening. One thing that might be of significance is that only pages that don't query the database seem to work every time.

UPDATE:

Just discovered something strange that might give more insite into the problem. If I type the following URLs:

localhost/index.php   // the home page is served up correctly

localhost/index.php?page=1   // the home page is served up correctly

localhost/index.php?page=home   // ERROR: index.php is downloaded !!!!!!!!!!

localhost/index.php?page=contact   // the contact page is served up correctly

localhost/index.php?page=blog   // ERROR: index.php is downloaded

localhost/index.php?page=10   // the blog page is served up correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of [index.php is not opening and running as download the file!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447021/index-php-is-not-opening-and-running-as-download-the-file)

Comment: have you restarted apache after installing php  ?

Answer (score 4):

Uncommenting the following line in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf fixed the problem for me:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with my PHP files downloading instead of rendering the page on an Apache local host and this fixed it for me. Very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding this to your conf or htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: This is already in my httpd.conf `<IfModule mime_module>AddType application/x-httpd-php .php</IfModule>`

Comment: Well in that case it could be a content-type issue, do a search for usage of header() and check there is nothing that might be making the browser download the file.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this was asked a long time ago, but I just encountered this problem so I thought I'd post what the cause was for me.

Make sure that you don't have...

**AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php**

...in BOTH your .htaccess file and your httpd.conf file.  Check your .htaccess file, comment it out, restart Apache, and try again.  That is most likely your problem since Apache renders php for some sites but not others.  It has to be at the directory level, which would point to a .htaccess file setting.

Answer (score -2):

I stumbled upon this problem after upgrading php to 5.5 and reinstalling apache.

Finally,this fixed it, in case someone else needs it.

`apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

([here's the answer](https://serverfault.com/a/243979/239598))