# Downloads PHP instead of Running

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a form that submits data to my database on mySQL workbench. When ever I click submit it ends up downloading the php file instead of running. All files are in the same folder.

inventorylog.html

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input required type="text" name="sku_input" placeholder="Sku #" />
    <br>
    <input value="Add Sku" type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $port=3306;
    $socket="/tmp/mysql.sock";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="Logs";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
        or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());   

    //$con->close();
?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
    /*Needs the connection object created in the connect.php file to work*/
    header("LOCATION:inventorylog.html");
    require('connect.php');
    /*require('inventorylog.html');*/

    /*Data from the html form is on the right. The objects that will be composed of that data is on the left.*/
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $skunum = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sku_input']);
    echo 'sku_input';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO skulist (sku_input) 
                          VALUES ('$skunum')";

        if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
        }

$con->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: how are you testing this?  your running a local wamp\lamp server?

Comment: @tim running it like -> http://localhost/inventorylog.html on chrome

Comment: remove the `header` .. line don't know what you think that's for.

Comment: It might be a problem with your server configuration. Try to change the insert.php code to something simple like `echo 'Hello';` and try again. If it still downloads the php file, you should look for a solution in the configuration.

Comment: @HonzaOne tried changing it to echo 'Hello'; Still downloads instead of running.

Comment: @tim got rid of the header. Doesn't change anything

Comment: I believe it is a server issue then. I am really sorry but I don't feel confident to help you with that. You may try to explore answers to similar questions. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083599/apache-downloads-php-files-instead-of-executing-script). If you don't find the answer, ask your own and specify what kind of server you use, OS etc. Good luck! :)