# Can't access phpmyadmin after installation

Tags: linux, ssh, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on my new server, following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04)

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

then added phpmyadmin to apache configuration:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

and restarted apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

All this by SSH.

But now when i try to access:   x.x.x.x/phpmyadmin all that i get is that my browser downloads a file... Can someone help with this?

Comment: sounds like you don't have PHP installed / configured correctly.  as per the guide you referenced "Before working with phpMyAdmin you need to have LAMP installed on your server. If you don't have the Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP stack on your server, you can find the tutorial for setting it up here..."

Comment: well, PHP is working on my website, located in home/xxx/public_html/site.com     maybe i have to configure something else to have it working also with phpmyadmin?

Comment: is the file downloaded the phpmyadmin index page?  check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447021/index-php-is-not-opening-and-running-as-download-the-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are sure that you do have lamp-stack just open up your terminal and edit

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and paste the following at the end of file

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Save the file and restart using `sudo service apache2 restart`

You can also visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin for more details.

Comment: After doing that I also had to restart using sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 8):

You can do two things I guess, as I've experienced both of them :
1. you need to add

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

2. Add this line at last or somewhere in code:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

3. restart :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but this didn't worked for me(apache2 failed to restart), as it worked for many. 
Otherwise you can eve try:

```
ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-phpmyadmin
```

Or

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

and under webserver select: apache.

Comment: The option to reconfigure via `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` really helps to keep reattempting to get it right the "auto way" until it works.  Thank you.