# (weird) wamp server 2.5 just running localhost and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, wamp

I installed WAMP server 2.5 (not the first time. I installed on my other laptop which works fine).

It seems that WAMP is running fine because the WAMP icon turns green and I’m able to open localhost and PHPMyAdmin but, the problem occurs when I try to run other PHP files, the Chrome shows the PHP code as it is and IE downloads the file.

I can run index file from localhost but when I drag drop index file it doesn't work.

Comment: Which _problem_? Do you encounter any error message?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447021/index-php-is-not-opening-and-running-as-download-the-file

Comment: You need to check in your `apache.conf` `LoadModule php5_module "path/php5apache2_4.dll"` path is correct and there is no `#` at the beginning if so remove it or enable php module from wamp directly

Comment: @MartinZabel, no i don't encounter any error message. it just shows the code as it is.

Comment: @Armen, i checked that httpd.conf file this is the line i got. pleae check and tell me if its correct or no `so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so

LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll"`

Comment: Seems path is ok, i rechecked your question and now i realized that  you are telling that you are able to open it with localhost/project/index.php link normally yes php is working there ? and just it not working and giving to download php files on drag end drop on browser yes or ?

Comment: @Armen, if i goto Wamp server green icon and click localhost then the index file works. but if i run that index file manually by drag drop then it doesn't work and chrome shows the code of that file inside browser and internet explorer downloads the file.

Comment: You can't open `php` files by drag and drop to browser with link like `file:///C:/Users/index.php` it will be not processed by wamp's `php server` + `apache` you will nigher see its content nigher download it. You should always run php files through localhost/path/index.php or through virtual hosts, for mor info about virtual hosts you can check this article - https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

Answer (score 0):

> I can run index file from localhost but when I drag drop index file it
>   doesn't work.

Yes, this is expected behavior. Not just on WAMP but absolutely any local LAMP-based web development setup. Dragging and dropping a file like `index.php` won’t actually get the LAMP setup to parse the file.

PHP needs to be processed by an interpreter to get it run. Either from the command line or via a web server with a PHP interpreter setup as a module. When you drag and drop the file into a browser, that file never gets processed via the web server.

To get PHP processed and run it *must* simply be run via a URL connected to that local development server; such as the address `http://localhost/index.php` or `http://localhost/` since an `index.php` should be automatically loaded by the web server as a directory index.